# Return value problems for a templated BST method

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, tree, return-value

I have this code for a function that's purpose is to decrypt a message that's given by a string of the characters r, 0, and 1. The idea is that i have a BST, and based on my string of r 0 and 1 i will be able to find a pathway to the specific data i am looking for.

I simply cannot figure out what to return to match the return value of the function and get the information from the function that I am looking for! Here is the help the professor gives...

```
 /*The decrypt() method takes an encrypted string (or path through the tree)
in the form provided by encrypt(). It should return a pointer to the 
associated string for the given path (or NULL if the path is invalid).*/
```

Can anyone help talk me through how to return the right variable type and value, and explain why? Thanks! (Code below)

```
template<class Base>
const Base * EncryptionTree<Base>::decrypt(const string & path) const{
    const BSTNode<Base>* temp = root;
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
        switch (path[i]) {
        case 'r':
            if (temp != NULL) {
                temp = root;
            }
            else {
                flag = true;
            }
            break;
        case '0':
            if (temp->getLeft() != NULL) {
                temp = temp->getLeft();
            }
            else {
                flag = true;
            }
            break;
        case '1':
            if (temp->getRight() != NULL) {
                temp = temp->getRight();
            }
            else {
                flag = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return ?????;
}
```

I tried returning *temp, temp, temp->getData() (returns a const Base &), etc.

Comment: "I am having trouble" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: thanks for your input, do you have any suggestions for the solution to my problem?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong (as I didn't see the declaration of Base and BSTNode) but if temp->getData() returns const Base&, then the end of your decrypt function might look like this:

```
if (temp != NULL)
    return &temp->getData();
else
    return NULL;
```

So if temp is **not null**, you're using *getData()* to get the reference to object (in your case string) this node contains. And then you're taking an address of an object this reference is bound to and pass it back to the caller.